# Julia: "Method error" while calling a parametric function

Tags: julia

In a file named "func.jl", I defined the following function:

```
function testXYZ(xi::Array{T, 1}, yi::Array{T, 1}) where {T<:Float64}
    println("Success")
end
```

In "main.jl" I did build a minimum example:

```
include("func.jl");
xs = [0.0, 1.2, 2.0, 5.0, 10.0, 11.0]
ys = [2.0, 2.1, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0]
testXYZ(xs, ys)
```

Checking with the console the types of xs and ys, I obtain as expected:

```
julia> ys = [2.0, 2.1, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0];
julia> typeof(ys)
Array{Float64,1}
```

While exectuting the minimum example in main I obtain a method error:

> ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching
>   +(::Array{Float64,1}, ::String)

In [Julia manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/), I found lots of similar errors, but no one solved my problem.

Comment: Your minimal working example is actually working: https://tio.run/##VU/LaoUwFFz3fMUhKwMhqH0sbLu4m/sDddHb0oVopJEQJYmoiN@emyhYehaH85hhZrpRySqbvW9HXXcK3xEIIRA3J3uNTlj3eftKZlkUF2OqZS0ZZhvD5f@B4vQrjMC1fCuuqq/cy9MGGGowUjulE/Ix1rWwllAQutlFoB9EeEQt3inCkEyEYtNjCw@TkU4kLcPD10ECqWs1NuKPQ19htsH0d8rTYIPnDPM4Pe/rccx4@gPLjtp/Oc8iNEzp2R4j5sxqQzxLvb8D

Comment: Dear @mschauer, that is interesting. Is it possible that the problem is given by the fact I am using the last version of Julia? (v1.3)

Comment: no -- your example works in v1.3 too.  What are you doing to run this? Do you use the full filepath or else are you sure Julia is in the right directory (try `julia> pwd()`)?

Comment: Dear @JeffreySarnoff, I discovered that the error was in another part of the code, whereas the error string lead me to erroneously think to the question object. Thank you!

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the code above. It says that it cannot perform `+` with two arrays of floats which is fine, however there is no call of `+` in your example. I think you are mixing up your files maybe?

Comment: You may want to try restarting your Julia session to make sure the `testXYZ` function is defined the way you think it is.

Comment: @tamasgal totally true. Thanks

Comment: @JoeMatt glad to help! Have fun with Julia :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @tamasgal comment, the correct answer is: 
"The error hasnothing to do with the code above. It says that it cannot perform + with two arrays of floats which is fine, however there is no call of + in your example."